# How to catch an exception from a private member subclass object?

Tags: c++

Given the pseudo-code below, I want to catch the exception thrown by the sub-object a in class B, maintaining this object private in B. The catch clause as stated below doesn't work because the object a is private in B. How can I catch this exception ?

**Edit**  I have changed the pseudo-code to embed class A within class B.

```
class B
{
    class A
    {
        public:
        class Exception{};
        A() throw(Exception) { ... }  // A ctor throws an Exception class object
    } a;
    public:
    B() { ... }     //  B ctor
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        B b;
    }
    catch( B::A::Exception& )
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: If the exception is meant to be caught in other classes, then it shouldn't be private

Comment: Thanks for totally changing the meaning of the question... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a typedef to the exception in the surrounding class.

```
class B
{
    class A
    {
        public:
        class Exception{};
        A() throw(Exception) {  }  // A ctor throws an Exception class object
    } a;

public:
  typedef A::Exception Except;
    B() {  }     //  B ctor
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        B b;
    }
    catch( B::Except& )
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: As you can see I've just edited my question to embed class A inside B. Thanks.

Comment: @user1162978 Effectively making this easier. Just use a `typedef`. Please don't use ellipsis in your code samples. This makes `copy-paste-compile` harder on people trying to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to say `B::A::Exception` in the `catch` clause, unless the class `A` is defined inside `B`.  Now that you've edited it to *make* it so, `B::A::Exception` is appropriate *if*  `A` is visible outside of `B` and `Exception` is visible outside of `A`...or if `B::A::Exception` is *made* available some other way (like via a typedef, [as suggested by pmr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272340/319403)).

And if it isn't, you shouldn't be throwing it at all.  (It's not, in this case, so yeah.  Don't do that.)  How is anyone going to reasonably catch that exception if they can't even see the type of it?

A way you could make this work is to split the declaration of the class from the declaration of the member variable.  Kinda like

```
class B {
 public:
    B() { }

    class A {
     public:
        class Exception {};
        A() { /* throw Exception(); */ }
    };
 private:
    A a;
};
```

But frankly, the typedef sounds way more elegant.

Comment: As you can see I've just edited my question to embed class A inside B. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, stop that.  :P  It changes the meaning of the question to a point that invalidates any answer already given.  If your question has changed that much, it's generally better to ask a new question.

Comment: The problem is that while A is visible within B, the object a is private in B, so the expression B::A::Exception& is not valid in main().

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rethink throwing exceptions in a constructor. [Here's why](http://herbsutter.com/2008/07/25/constructor-exceptions-in-c-c-and-java/) (the destructor will not get called when you throw an exception)

Exceptions are really for exceptional circumstances. Don't overuse them.

Comment: Destructors will get called just fine unless your C++ compiler is broken, or you're counting on destructing an object you never actually constructed.

Comment: @cHao: the destructor of a class is not called if the exception is thrown during the constructor. The object is not fully formed until the constructor ends and therefore this semantic is reasonable.

Comment: @6502: That's what i'm saying...if you never managed to construct the object, why should it be destructed?

Comment: @cHao: What carleeto is saying is that exception throwing in constructor contains some subtleties that can be dangerous. The idea of not calling the destructor on a partially constructed object is reasonable, but can still be surprising (because you have to manually take care of undoing the partial construction possibly duplicating code). Even worse if the object is being allocated using a placement new call because in this case there is no way to free the memory (C++ will call `operator delete` on an object being allocated using regular `new`, but there is no concept of "placement delete").

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` is private, you can't access the type `Exception` to catch it. There are a few solutions, first is catch anything:

```
try {
    B b;
} catch(...) {
}
```

Second is to create a separated Exception class that is visible in main.

And finally, you could make your `B::A::Exception` extend `std::Exception` and catch `std::Exception`.